# Elasticsearch multiple analyzers for a single field

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I store different kinds of documents in a single index with strict predefined mapping. All of them have some field (say, "body"), but I'd want them to be analyzed slightly differently when indexed (for example, to use different token filters for specific documents) and treaten the same way while searched. As far as I know, analyzers can't be specified per document.

What I also considered to use:

1. Object fields with differently analyzed subfields for document kinds, so each document has only one filled subfield (like, "body.mail", "body.html"). The problem is that I couldn't search on the whole "body" field which would look through all its subfields (to not break the existing application).
2. New reincarnation of multi-fields (to have "body" field with a generic analyzer and custonly analyzed "mail", "html", etc. inside it). Hovewer, I'm not sure if it's possible to use them directly while indexing and indirectly while searching (e.g., to save object with `{"mail":"smth"}` to use a specific index analyzer, then search by `"query":{"body":"smth"}` to use generic search analyzer).
3. To separate "body" into several fields with different mappings, remove them from `_all`, and set `copy_to` to a single `body` field. I'm not sure, but it will add a substantial index overhead due to copying.

Comment: Why not index different fields such as "mail", "html" etc, have a different analyzer for each, and use a multi match query to search on all these fields?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: In my opinion, these two requirements are not possible together: `search on the whole "body" field which would look through all its subfields (**to not break the existing application**)` and `analyzed slightly differently when indexed and treaten the same way while searched`. Something's got to give.

Comment: @Ita Legacy reasons. There's a lot of search queries on that field already, so it'd be hard and boilerplate-prone to replace each with multi match.

Comment: "`copy_to` to a single `body` field" will use the analyzer of the `body` field so, even if you had different analyzers on the fields that have `copy_to` in the end inside `body` you will get text analyzed by the `body` field analyzer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, what you want is not possible. Your requirement, in one sentence, is: have the same data analyzed in multiple ways, but searched as a single field because this would break the existing application.

```
             -- body.html          
             -- body.email
body field ---- body.content     --- all searched as "body"
            ...
             -- body.destination
             -- body.whatever
```

- Your first option is *multi-fields* which has this exact purpose in mind: have the same data analyzed multiple ways. The problem is that you cannot search for `"body"` and expect ES to search `body.html`, `body.email`... Even if this would be possible, you want to be searched with different analyzers. Again, not possible. This option requires you to **change the application** and search for each field in a `multi_match` or in a `query_string`.
- Your second option - `reincarnation of multi-fields` - will again not work because **you cannot refer to `body` and ES, in the background, to match `mail`, `content`** etc.
- Third option - using `copy_to` - will not work because copying to another field "X" means indexing the data being copied **will be analyzed with `X`'s analyzer**, and this breaks your requirement of having the same data analyzed differently.
- There could be a fourth option - [`"path": "just_name"` from `multi_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/mapping-multi-field-type.html#_accessing_fields) - which at a first look it should work. Meaning, you can have 3 multi-fields (email, content, html) which all three have a `body` sub-field. Having `"path": "just_name"` allows you to search just for `body` even if `body` is a sub-field of multiple other fields. But this is not possible because this type of multi-fields **will not accept different analyzers for the same `body`**.

**Either way, you need to change something in your requirements, because they will not work they way you want it.**

---

These being said, I'm curious to see what queries are you using in your application. It would be a simple change (*yes, you will need to change your app*) from querying `body` field to querying `body.*` in a `multi_match`.

And I have another solution for you: create multiple indices, one index for each analyzer of your `body`. For example, for `mail`, `content` and `html` you define three indices:

```
PUT /multi_fields1
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "whitespace",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT /multi_fields2
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "standard",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
PUT /multi_fields3
{
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "body": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "keyword",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You see that all of them have the same `type` and the same field name - `body` - but different `index_analyzer`s. Then you define an alias:

```
POST _aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {"add": {
        "index": "multi_fields1",
        "alias": "multi"}},
    {"add": {
        "index": "multi_fields2",
        "alias": "multi"}},
    {"add": {
        "index": "multi_fields3",
        "alias": "multi"}}
  ]
}
```

Name your alias the same as your current index. The application doesn't need to change, it will use the same name for index search, **but** this name will not point to an index, but to an alias which in turn refers to your multiple indices. What needs to change is how you index the documents, because a `html` documents needs to go in `multi_fields1` index for example, an `email` document needs to be index in `multi_fields2` index etc.

Whatever solution you find/choose, your requirements need to change because the way you want it is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use multi-field. With multi-field you can define analyzers (both indexing & searching) for each sub fields, and do the search on corresponding fields base on applications requirements.
In general, index analyzer can be difference from field to field, the same for search analyzer.

```
{
  "your_type" : {   
    "properties":{
        "body" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "analyzed",
            "index_analyzer" : "index_body_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer" : "search_body_analyzer",
            "fields" : {
                "mail" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "analyzed",
                    "index_analyzer" : "index_bodymail_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer" : "search_bodymail_analyzer"
                },
                "html": {
                    "type" : "string",              
                    "index" : "analyzed",
                    "index_analyzer" : "index_bodyhtml_analyzer",
                    "search_analyzer" : "search_bodyhtml_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to index data "into" `html` field (with its index_analyzer), then do the search on `body` field (with its search_analyzer)? The latter is crucial for backward compatibility.

Comment: You mean index difference data into `html` ? or the same data with `body`, just difference in index_analyzer ? If same data then ES already did it for you through multi-field definitions. You can provide sample data on the question to make things clear.

Comment: I mean to index objects like `[{"id":1,"html":"..."},{"id":2,"mail":"..."}]` (or `"body.html":"..."`, etc.) to use different index analyzers, but to search like `"query":"body:smth"` to use single search analyzer.
I'm currently experimenting with mappings, but still can't make my old search interface (which uses `body` in queries) work.

Comment: In that case we need to change the query to search across fields, otherwise I think it's impossible. Another partial solution is to pre-process documents at application level (before indexing), or writing an analyzer that can "if-else" at index time by your-self.