# analyzing a single elasticsearch field in different ways

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to know how can I analyze an elasticsearch field with two different analyzers at the same time. I am creating an elasticsearch plugin so, I need the java code to implement the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elasticsearch multiple analyzers for a single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943160/elasticsearch-multiple-analyzers-for-a-single-field)

Comment: @dishant are you creating index from Java or do you want to apply on existing index from java

Comment: @SagarPatel Yes, I want to create an index for testing purpose and store an email address in it from plugin itself and analyze it with multiple analyzers to get different tokens from both in a single place. But in production, the index will be present so I can implement the analyzer on the field directly without creating the index.

Comment: you want analyzer output as well in plugin itself ?

Comment: @Dishant check my answer belwo for Java API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Create Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-create-index.html#java-rest-high-create-index) in java code for creating index with multi field

```java
CreateIndexRequest request = new CreateIndexRequest("twitter");

Map<String, Object> email_second = new HashMap<>();
email_second.put("type", "text");
email_second.put("analyzer", "custom_standard");

Map<String, Object> email = new HashMap<>();
email.put("type", "text");
email.put("analyzer", "standard");
email.put("fields", "email_second");


Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("email", email);
Map<String, Object> mapping = new HashMap<>();
mapping.put("properties", properties);
request.mapping(mapping);

CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse = client.indices().create(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

you can access first email field with `email` and second with `email.email_second` name.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) to achieve the same. Refer [multiple analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html#_multi_fields_with_multiple_analyzers) section in the document with example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually I want to do it in java. I am creating an elasticsearch custom plugin which will be installed inside the elasticsearch.